# java 1.3 to 1.4 text resource local elements (resource bundle)

Tags: java, localization

I have an old program original written for java 1.3 that trys to get resource bundle :

java.text.resources.LocaleElements

and if that fails trys :

sun.text.resources.LocaleElements

```
ResourceBundle r=null;
try {
    r = ResourceBundle.getBundle("java.text.resources.LocaleElements", zomLocale);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    try {
        r = ResourceBundle.getBundle("sun.text.resources.LocaleElements", zomLocale);
    }
    catch (Exception ex1) {
        ex1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This worked fine in 1.3 but these bundles do not exist in java 1.4.

I don't now enough about java as to know:

1. Where these resources comes from or
2. How I install them or
3. How to list what resource bundles are now available in 1.4 or
4. If I can simply provide the new/replacement name for the resource I want/need

I don't even know how I came up with the original resource bundle names in the first place.

I suppose the simplest solution for me is to determine what are the replacements for these missing bundles.

I'm using netbeans 12.2 maven (Ubuntu 20.04) if that make any difference!

Edit:

looking at the jdk packages :

https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/14.0/package?package=sun.text.resources

I can see that "LocaleElements" no longer exists.  A general search doesn't find anything for LocaleElements.  So maybe the technique I was employing  isn't valid anymore.

If the only thing I need out of LocaleElements is "DateTimePatterns" are there any suggestions how I should instead be doing this?

Comment: This https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4236976 implies that they were moved to the `sun.text.resources` package in 1.4, but you don't see them there...

Comment: I'd suggest copying them from a 1.3 distribution and putting them into your own project.

Comment: @tgdavies What do you mean ... in package 1.4, but you don't see them there ...?  Are they there or not?

Comment: Is there some method preferable to using using those bundles if they don't exist anymore? The only thing I get out of the bundle is the "DateTimePattern".  So should I be doing this differently?

Comment: Looking in the Java Package browser on https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/14.0. I can see there are no LocalElements for sun.text.resources.  So as you suggested I could copy this from 1.3 but maybe I should change the code to do this another way.